# I'm struggling to determine what dropdown element is selected

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to display input fields when the user selects a certain element from the dropdown component. I tried to do this by adding an eventListener onto the dropdown component but this does not seem to work.

When I inspect the page and go to sources -> event listener breakpoint I see that it detects the mouse click event but when I try to add an eventListener I get the following error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". This is the code for the dropdown component:

```
{
    PlaceHSolder: "",
    Fields:[{
        Name:"The color of the car",
        Label: 'The color of the car',
        Type:'Lookup',
        Fields: ['id', 'color'],
        FieldValues:[ 
            {"id":"1", "color":"red",id: '1red'},
            {"id":"2", "color":"blue",id: '2blue'},
            {"id":"3", "color":"green",id: '3green'}
        ],
        LabelField: 'color',
        ValueField: 'id',
        IsSingle:   true,
        triggerAction: 'all' ,
        queryParam: 'q',
        queryMode: 'remote',
        listeners: {
            select: function () {
                console.log( this.getValue());
            }
        },
        renderTo: document.body
    }],
    Required:  false
}
```

I am unsure as to what exactly is wrong in my code as I am relatively new. To give a more clear explanation of what I want to do, here is a picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQQwH.jpg

In this picture I have a dropdown component where I want to select the blue element. After that I am planning to let go the dropdown and show various other labels and components depending on which text the user selects.

Using the inspection tool in Google Chrome shows me the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e708P.jpg

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm observing `fieldvalues` multiple `id` attribute. Which one is correct. I guess you are using this select `id` value for getting another element. So, incorrect `id` value is passed due to that element is not found.

Comment: Dont forget the: "  xtype: 'combobox'  "

Comment: Can you attach the code of `addEventListener` ?